# Searching list of strings using regular expressions in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of Strings. I want to select the strings which match a certain pattern using regular expression. 
Python regular expressions dont take a list and I dont want to use loops.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why don't you want to use loops? You seem to know the basics of how to approach this, but are stating that it's a constraint that you can't... So.... errr? Would `filter` suffice?

Comment: because loops are slow and I have a very big list

Comment: loops are very slow... really? Premature optimisation and all that...

Comment: Can you give an example of the code your working on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
def searcher(s):
    if COMPILED_REGEXP_OBJECT.search(s):
        return s

matching_strings = filter(searcher, YOUR_LIST_OF_STRING)
```

`searcher()` returns the string if it matches, else returns `None`.  `filter()` only returns "true" objects, so will skip the `None`s.  It will also skip empty strings, but doubt that's a problem.

Or, better, as @JonClements pointed out:

```
matching_strings = filter(COMPILED_REGEXP_OBJECT.search, YOUR_LIST_OF_STRING)
```

Not only shorter, it only looks up the `.search` method once (instead of once per string).